# Build JSON with sub levels

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to build JSON as below.

```
{
  "nameInfo": {
    "name": "Bhanu"
  }
}
```

I tried below code and its working fine.

```
a = {}
a.nameInfo = {}
a.nameInfo.name="John"
console.log(a)
```

However, just checking if there is a better way to do the same thing. Do I always have to initialize a.nameInfo to empty object before adding a property under nameInfo?

Comment: `a.nameInfo = { name: 'John' }` or directly `a = { nameInfo: { name: 'John' } }`

Comment: This is sort of correct.  When you are writing 'use strict' you should always declare your variables and avoid using them without at least `var` or `let` because this is scoped to the `window` otherwise.

Comment: You’re building an object, not JSON. If you want JSON, use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey good call.  Words matter.  But if we overlook the fact that Bhanu is newer to javascript JS Objects are similar to JSON in the same sense that JSON actually means JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: @Moosecouture are numbers similar to strings? You could say “1.01” is in JavaScript number format, since you can parse it as a number. Also, when someone is new to a language is precisely the time to intervene so that bad habits don’t settle in.

Comment: Not sure I follow the number string point.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to do the following:

```
let a = {
  nameInfo: {
    name: 'Bhanu'
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe "easiest" is not the right word. Even his one is really easy. Let's say the "most compact way"

Comment: Point taken.  I think this is the Clearest and most Compact and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

different way, still JS object

```js
var a = { };
a['nameInfo'] = { name: 'Bhanu' };

console.log(a);
```